# how to read this facebook leads sample code

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0

i have made a successful login using facebook but i want to run this sample code where can i place this sample to test it

```
use FacebookAds\Api;
use FacebookAds\Http\RequestInterface;

$params = array(
  'user_id' => <USER_ID>,
);

$response = Api::instance()->call(
  '/me/leadgen_whitelisted_users',
  RequestInterface::METHOD_POST,
  $params);
```

i put it after login then i get this error `Call to a member function call() on a non-object`

Comment: Is that namespace `FacebookAds\...` correct? If it's a third party library, you will hve to read their documentation, or provide its name.

Comment: @CarlosCarucce i got it from this link https://developers.facebook.com/ads/blog/post/2016/01/20/leadgen-whitelisted-users/

Comment: try this one: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/leadgen_whitelisted_users/

Comment: `Api::instance()` isn't returning the object you expect. Have you followed the installation instructions for the Facebook Ads PHP API here: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-ads-sdk